# Using a colorbar to append colors to a bar graph by given values MATLAB

Tags: matlab, colormap

Consider the following `bar` graph

```
figure
bar([2 4 8; 1 2 3; 3 3 3],'stacked')
```

[image]

I would like each bar to have a color which will correspond to a colormap (here, between `[0,1]`), such that every bar get a color that matches the following data

```
data = [0.1 0.8 0.1; 0.5 0.5 0.2; 0.6 0.3 0.9];
```

Comment: I guess you mean colormap instead of colorbar? How should it be defined, as in how many discrete color levels should it contain?

Comment: @Matteo The colormap/colorbar is defined between [0,1], i.e if it is a grayscale, where 0 is black and 1 is white, for the first column in the bar graph, the blue and yellow will turn dark gray (0.1), and the orange (middle) will turn light gray (0.8)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'CData' argument to set the color of the faces individually. You just need to remember to set 'FaceColor' as 'flat' also.

```
b = bar([2 4 8; 1 2 3; 3 3 3], 'stacked');
data = [0.1 0.8 0.1; 0.5 0.5 0.2; 0.6 0.3 0.9];

for i = 1:length(b)
    b(i).CData = repmat(data(i, :)', [1, 3]); % use your data as grayscale color level
    b(i).FaceColor = 'flat';
end
```

EDIT:
In case I've mistaken the order you wanted the colors in your colormap, you should change the Cdata call to `b(i).Cdata = repmat(data(:, i), [1, 3]);` instead. Not sure which one you wanted.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me on both R2018b and R2019a.